# ADFS - Failed to acquire token silently as no token was found in the cache. Call method AcquireToken

Tags: adfs, adal

I am trying to call the AcquireTokenSilentAsync and it fails with the error message unable to read the values from the cache, please find the code snippet for the same.Please let me know what I am doing wrong here

**AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync**

```cs
ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value;

UserIdentifier userIdentifier = 
    new UserIdentifier(signedInUserID, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId); 
AuthenticationContext authContext = 
    new AuthenticationContext(Authority, false, new RedisTokenCache(signedInUserID));

AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
    code, 
    new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)),
    credential, 
    resourceId);
```

**AcquireTokenSilentAsync**

```cs
string signedInUserID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value; 
UserIdentifier userIdentifier = 
    new UserIdentifier(signedInUserID, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId);  
ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);

AuthenticationContext authContext = 
    new AuthenticationContext(Authority, false, new RedisTokenCache(signedInUserID));  
var token = 
    await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(resourceId, credential, userIdentifier);
```

**RedisCache**

```cs
 public class RedisTokenCache : TokenCache
    {
        private string userId;
        private UserTokenCacheItem Cache;

        public RedisTokenCache(string signedInUserId)
        {
            // associate the cache to the current user of the web app
            userId = signedInUserId;
            this.AfterAccess = AfterAccessNotification;
            this.BeforeAccess = BeforeAccessNotification;
            this.BeforeWrite = BeforeWriteNotification;
            // look up the entry in the cache
            var cache = Redis.Connection.GetDatabase();
            try
            {
                var cachedItem = cache.StringGet(userId);
                if (cachedItem.HasValue)
                {
                    Cache = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserTokenCacheItem>(cachedItem);
                    this.Deserialize((Cache == null) ? null : MachineKey.Unprotect(Cache.cacheBits, "ADALCache"));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine("Exception in RedisTokenCache(id): " + ex.Message);
                Cache = null;
            }
        }

        // clean up the database
        public override void Clear()
        {
            base.Clear();
            try
            {
                var cache = Redis.Connection.GetDatabase();
                cache.KeyDelete(userId);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine("Exception in RedisTokenCache.Clear: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        // Notification raised before ADAL accesses the cache.
        // This is your chance to update the in-memory copy from the cache, if the in-memory version is stale
        void BeforeAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
        {
            try
            {
                var cache = Redis.Connection.GetDatabase();
                var cachedItem = cache.StringGet(userId);
                if (cachedItem.HasValue)
                {
                    var status = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserTokenCacheItem>(cachedItem);
                    if ((Cache != null) && (status.LastWrite > Cache.LastWrite))
                    {
                        Cache = status;
                        this.Deserialize((Cache == null) ? null : MachineKey.Unprotect(Cache.cacheBits, "ADALCache"));
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine("Exception in RedisTokenCache.BeforeAccessNotification: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        // Notification raised after ADAL accessed the cache.
        // If the HasStateChanged flag is set, ADAL changed the content of the cache
        void AfterAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
        {
            // if state changed
            if (this.HasStateChanged)
            {
                Cache = new UserTokenCacheItem
                {
                    cacheBits = MachineKey.Protect(this.Serialize(), "ADALCache"),
                    LastWrite = DateTime.Now
                };
                try
                {
                    var cache = Redis.Connection.GetDatabase();
                    var cacheItemJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Cache);
                    cache.StringSet(userId, cacheItemJson, TimeSpan.FromDays(1)); // could we use token expiry somehow?
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Trace.WriteLine("Exception in RedisTokenCache.AfterAccessNotification: " + ex.Message);
                }
                this.HasStateChanged = false;
            }
        }
        void BeforeWriteNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
        {
            // if you want to ensure that no concurrent write take place, use this notification to place a lock on the entry
        }

        public override void DeleteItem(TokenCacheItem item)
        {
            base.DeleteItem(item);
            try
            {
                var cache = Redis.Connection.GetDatabase();
                var cachedItem = cache.KeyDelete(userId);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine("Exception in RedisTokenCache.DeleteItem: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Redis
    {
        // Redis Connection string info
        private static Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> lazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
        {
            string cacheConnection = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:CacheConnection"].ToString();
            return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(cacheConnection);
        });

        public static ConnectionMultiplexer Connection
        {
            get
            {
                return lazyConnection.Value;
            }
        }
    }
    public class UserTokenCacheItem
    {
        public byte[] cacheBits { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastWrite { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: How did you implement the `RedisTokenCache`? Did you check that the token exited in the Redis?

Comment: Redis cache is having the data and it is reading it from the cache.

Comment: Which line of code caused this issue?

Comment: When authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(resourceId, credential, userIdentifier); is called it is giving the exception.

Comment: To narrow down this issue, I suggest that you enable the log for the ADAL library to find the root cause. Here are some hints maybe also helpful to root the reason. Did you get the refresh token when you acquire the access token first time? Is the resource same from the two requests? And to enable the log, you can refer this [link](https://www.schaeflein.net/adal-v3-diagnostic-logging/).

Comment: Thanks @FeiXue-MSFT your suggestion help me resolve the issue, updating the useridentifier in AcquireTokenSilentAsync fixed the issue.            string signedInUserID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
            UserIdentifier userIdentifier = new UserIdentifier(signedInUserID, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId);